# How to sucessfully call a BOOL method in an if statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, comparison, return-value

*Updated:*

I am trying to call a method from a different class and put it in an `if` statement saying "if the `uploadPhoto` method is true then display success for testing purposes" here is my updated code:

```
PhotoScreen *script = [[PhotoScreen alloc] init];

if ([script uploadPhoto])
{
    NSLog(@"Sucess!");
}
```

It isn't giving me the error anymore but when I summit the photo from the uploadPhoto method, it does't log the "Success" And here is my uploadPhoto method:

```
- (BOOL)uploadPhoto
{
    //upload the image and the title to the web service
    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"upload",@"command",
      UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo.image,70),@"file",
      fldTitle.text, @"title",nil]
      onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json)
      {
          //completion
         if (![json objectForKey:@"error"])
         {
             //success
             [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!"
                message:@"Your photo is uploaded"
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yay!"
                otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
         }
         else
         {
             //error, check for expired session and if so - authorize the user
             NSString* errorMsg = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
             [UIAlertView error:errorMsg];

             if ([@"Authorization required" compare:errorMsg]==NSOrderedSame) 
             {
                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];
             }
         }
     }];
     return YES;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your method return a `BOOL`? Also why are you calling it twice? Also you can just put `[script uploadPhoto]` in the if statement.

Comment: I just changed the method to return a BOOL and it isn't giving me an error anymore but it's not diplaying the "Sucess" when I try to upload a photo. Is there a way I can make it where: once the method is called then display the text?

Comment: It's only going to log "success" if your `uploadPhoto` method returns `YES` (BTW - only use `YES` or `NO` for `BOOL` values). Perhaps you should post your `uploadPhoto` method in your question.

Comment: This method `uploadPhoto` doesn't seem to return anything. Then you will get an undefined value in comparison expression.

Comment: Have you used "return YES;" on success and "return NO;" on failure ?

Comment: @Student This is an asynchronous operation, and we cannot return the result immediately as a return value of this method.

Comment: Yeah I just put RETURN YES: at the end of the method and it's still not working :/

Comment: @user3807138 Try to print "failure!" by adding an `else` block. And tell us what happens.

Comment: See also similar questions: [Return result of completion block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12095784), [Why can't I return an object from my block?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8436750), [Completion handlers and return values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16254756)

Answer (score 1):

You method needs to return a `BOOL`. In your method you should have the statement `return YES;` somewhere if the method succeeds and a `return NO;` if it fails. You can modify your code to the following:

```
PhotoScreen *script = [[PhotoScreen alloc] init];

if ([script uploadPhoto])
{
    NSLog(@"Sucess!");
}
```

The repetitive method calls were unnecessary along with the comparison.